# $L_{\Sigma^*}=\{\langle M\rangle|L(M)=\Sigma^*\}\notin coRE$

Tags: formal-languages, computability

I'm trying to understand why:
$$L_{\Sigma^*}=\{\langle M\rangle|L(M)=\Sigma^*\}\notin coRE$$
As I see it TM, $\langle M\rangle$, should accept all the inputs, and if one of the inputs rejected it's not $L(M)=\Sigma^*$ any more, so why it's not? $$L_{\Sigma^*}\in coRE$$

$*$ I familiar with the reductions $HP\le L_{\Sigma^*}$ and $HP\le \overline{L_{\Sigma^*}}$ to proof $L_{\Sigma^*}, \overline{L_{\Sigma^*}}\notin RE$

Answer (score 1):

You say

> $\langle M \rangle$ should accept all the inputs, and if one of the inputs rejected it's not $L(M)=\Sigma^∗$.

The above two statements are true, but you are not handling all behaviors of $M$.
In particular you are not considering that $M$ could never halt on some input $x$. In that case $L(M) \neq \Sigma^*$.

In short, your observation do not imply the existence of a Turing machine that accepts on input $M$ whenever $L(M) \neq \Sigma^*$, which would show $\overline{L_{\Sigma^*}} \in \mathsf{RE}$.

In fact, you can formally prove that $\overline{L_{\Sigma^*}} \not\in \mathsf{RE}$ by reducing from the halting problem:
for any Turing machine $T$ you can construct another machine $M_T$ that simulates $T$ and then accepts.
If $\overline{L_{\Sigma^*}}$ were in RE, then there would be a Turing machine $T^*$ that accepts iff $M_T \in \overline{L_{\Sigma^*}}$, i.e., iff $T$ does not halt.
Interleaving the execution of $T^*$ with that of $T$ itself allows  you to solve the halting problem.

Comment: Thank you, I read your answer few times but I can't understand it. I'm missing something.. in case I run the TM controlled run on number of steps and the input, in case if input the rejected in finite number of steps the controlled run should reach it. So it will be coRE. :(

Comment: In the following I'm referring to the problem of accepting $\overline{L_{\Sigma^*}}$.
What if the TM $M$ never accepts nor rejects? You can't simulate $M$ forever because you need to accept when $M$ never halts. Therefore you need to stop simulating $M$ at some point and accept. How do you decide when to stop? If you stop after $s$ steps, then maybe $M$ accepts all inputs after the $(s+1)$-th step, so you should not have accepted.

Comment: Thanks! I understood, for now, only $\overline{L_{\Sigma^*}}$ and how it force $L_{\Sigma^*}\notin coRE$, but still it's not an intuitive for some reason. Maybe I need more time to comprehend it.

Comment: I found why it's not clear for me, $\overline{L_{U}}$ as I see it is the same ($M$ does not accept $x$) and it's in $coRE$, what is the difference between $\overline{L_{U}}$ and $\overline{L_{\Sigma^*}}$? I mean not in definitions, why one in $coRE$ and the second one not?

Comment: You talk about $\overline{L_U}$ but that language is never mentioned anywhere in your question or my answer. What's the definition of $\overline{L_U}$?

Comment: $\overline{L_{U}}=\{ \langle M \rangle , x | M  does  not  accept  x\}$

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, I mean $L_{U}=\{ \langle M \rangle , x | M  accept  x\}$ and $\overline{L_{U}}\in coRE$

Comment: I prefer to equivalently talk about languages in $\mathsf{RE}$ (one less complement to take care of in my head).You're saying is that $L_U$ is in $\mathsf{RE}$ and "intuitively" this should also mean that $\overline{L_\Sigma} \in RE$.
However there is a big difference between $L_U$ and $\overline{L_\Sigma}$. In the former language $M$ **must halt** and accept on input $x$. In the second language $M$ can  **either** 1) reject on some input $x$ or 2) **run forever** on some input $x$. The "run forever" part is causing troubles. Without 2) $\overline{L_\Sigma}$ would be in $\mathsf{RE}$.